# How to convert Boost generated xml log file to allure report format

Tags: c++, boost, allure, test-suite

I have a XML log file generated from Boost C++ Unit test framework. I would like to generate an Allure report format for xml file generated from Boost C++.
Is it possible to generate an allure report for Boost test suite ? If so how can i do so
When i tried to create allure report it generated an empty allure report
I am currently using BOOST 1.71 Version

Can anyone help on this

If allure doesn't work out , could you please suggest how can we generate a report dashboard format just like allure for Boost generated logs.

Below is xml log file generated

```
<TestLog>
<TestSuite name="HW Verifier Tests">
    <TestSuite name="TEST_ENVIRONMENT_SUITE" file="D:\Users\ust5cob\Branch\HW_Verifier\TestManager\TestManager.cpp" line="1124">
        <TestCase name="Test_Environment" file="D:\Users\ust5cob\Branch\HW_Verifier\TestManager\TestManager.cpp" line="1125">
            <Info file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/TestCaseBase.cpp" line="680"><![CDATA[check m_device != "" has passed]]></Info>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="53"><![CDATA[Windows Name: Microsoft Enterprise Edition (build 9200), 64-bit]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="60"><![CDATA[Windows Version : 6.2 ]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="61"><![CDATA[Platform : Win32]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="92"><![CDATA[Processor : Intel(R) Xeon(R) E-2144G CPU @ 3.60GHz]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="106"><![CDATA[Username : ust5cob]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="112"><![CDATA[Computer name : COB-C-002QD]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="117"><![CDATA[System Directory : C:\WINDOWS\system32]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="122"><![CDATA[Windows Directory : C:\WINDOWS]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="126"><![CDATA[Locale : English]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="131"><![CDATA[Total Physical Memory : 34.1992 GB]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="132"><![CDATA[Available Physical Memory : 17.4302 GB]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="133"><![CDATA[Total Virtual Memory : 140737 GB]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="134"><![CDATA[Available Virtual Memory : 140732 GB]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="135"><![CDATA[Total Page file : 39.2994 GB]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="136"><![CDATA[Available Page file : 12.1219 GB]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="138"><![CDATA[version is : 1.0.0]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="140"><![CDATA[ED version is : 1.0.0]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="145"><![CDATA[H version is : 2.0.0.0]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/Test_Environment.cpp" line="147"><![CDATA[Boost Version : 107100]]></Message>
            <Exception file="unknown location" line="0">
                <![CDATA[timeout while executing function]]><LastCheckpoint file="D:\Users\ust5cob\Branch\HW_Verifier\TestCases\Others\TestCaseBase.cpp" line="680"><![CDATA[]]></LastCheckpoint>
            </Exception>
            <TestingTime>146400</TestingTime>
        </TestCase>
    </TestSuite>
    <TestSuite name="ES886" file="D:\Users\ust5cob\Branch\HW_Verifier\TestManager\TestManager.cpp" line="1151">
        <TestCase name="PCAPmin_Capture_Test" file="D:\Users\ust5cob\Branch\HW_Verifier\TestManager\TestManager.cpp" line="1172">
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestWrapper/EP_Wrapper.cpp" line="32"><![CDATA[Initialising EP Wrapper]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestWrapper/PCAPmin_Wrapper.cpp" line="37"><![CDATA[Initialising winpcap Wrapper]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="59"><![CDATA[PCAPmin Capture Test start]]></Message>
            <Info file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/TestCaseBase.cpp" line="680"><![CDATA[check m_device != "" has passed]]></Info>
            <Info file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="91"><![CDATA[check m_rtrID != "" has passed]]></Info>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="101"><![CDATA[PCAP file to be played by CAPman : eis_cpc_10Packets.pcap]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="103"><![CDATA[PCAP file to be played by CAPman : SOME_IP_SD_NO_VLAN_from_EKI.pcap]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="106"><![CDATA[Count Value for repeating the content of PCAP file : 10]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="108"><![CDATA[Count Value for repeating the content of PCAP file : 1]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="111"><![CDATA[Number of Tx messages in the PCAP file : eis_cpc_10Packets.pcap is 10]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="113"><![CDATA[Number of Tx messages in the PCAP file : eis_cpc_10Packets.pcap is 550]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="131"><![CDATA[Number of EPCI Devices : 1]]></Message>
            <Info file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="133"><![CDATA[check m_numberOfEPCIControllers != 0 has passed]]></Info>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="144"><![CDATA[---------------------------: EPCI URIs :---------------------------]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="149"><![CDATA[/EP]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="152"><![CDATA[---------------------------: PCAP URIs :---------------------------]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="164"><![CDATA[EP]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="1030"><![CDATA[Running test for AE Ports]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="378"><![CDATA[**********************************************Set EPCI Configuration  *********************************************************]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestWrapper/EP_Wrapper.cpp" line="68"><![CDATA[----------------------: EP Device Channel : :----------------------]]></Message>
            <Info file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestWrapper/EP_Wrapper.cpp" line="74"><![CDATA[check 'CSI Return Code : SUCCESS' has passed]]></Info>
            <Error file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestWrapper/EP_Wrapper.cpp" line="80"><![CDATA[CSI failed. Error code : 0x80002004. Error description : Unexpected error code]]></Error>
            <Error file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="416"><![CDATA[Error during EP session creation...]]></Error>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="431"><![CDATA[*******************************************************************************************************************************]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/PCAPmin/PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="72"><![CDATA[PCAPmin Capture Test End]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestWrapper/PCAPmin_Wrapper.cpp" line="50"><![CDATA[UnInitialising winpcap Wrapper]]></Message>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestWrapper/EP_Wrapper.cpp" line="44"><![CDATA[UnInitialising EPCI Wrapper]]></Message>
            <Exception file="unknown location" line="0">
                <![CDATA[timeout while executing function]]><LastCheckpoint file="D:\Users\ust5cob\Branch\HW_Verifier\TestCases\PCAPmin\PCAPmin_Capture_Test.cpp" line="416"><![CDATA[]]></LastCheckpoint>
            </Exception>
            <TestingTime>9562888</TestingTime>
        </TestCase>
    </TestSuite>
    <TestSuite name="DISABLED_TESTS_SUITE" file="D:\Users\ust5cob\Branch\HW_Verifier\TestManager\TestManager.cpp" line="1202">
        <TestCase name="Disabled_Tests" file="D:\Users\ust5cob\Branch\HW_Verifier\TestManager\TestManager.cpp" line="1203">
            <Info file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/TestCaseBase.cpp" line="680"><![CDATA[check m_device != "" has passed]]></Info>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/DisabledTests.cpp" line="43"><![CDATA[No. of Test cases disabled in Exxx Test suite :+ 0]]></Message>
            <Exception file="unknown location" line="0">
                <![CDATA[timeout while executing function]]><LastCheckpoint file="D:\Users\ust5cob\Branch\HW_Verifier\TestCases\Others\TestCaseBase.cpp" line="680"><![CDATA[]]></LastCheckpoint>
            </Exception>
            <TestingTime>13099</TestingTime>
        </TestCase>
    </TestSuite>
    <TestSuite name="HARDWARE_LOGS_SUITE" file="D:\Users\ust5cob\Branch\HW_Verifier\TestManager\TestManager.cpp" line="1209">
        <TestCase name="Hardware_Logs" file="D:\Users\ust5cob\Branch\HW_Verifier\TestManager\TestManager.cpp" line="1210">
            <Info file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/TestCaseBase.cpp" line="680"><![CDATA[check m_device != "" has passed]]></Info>
            <Message file="D:/Users/ust5cob/Branch/HW_Verifier/TestCases/Others/HardwareLogs.cpp" line="48"><![CDATA[Hardware logs location : <a href=HardwareLogs\>Click here</a\>]]></Message>
            <Exception file="unknown location" line="0">
                <![CDATA[timeout while executing function]]><LastCheckpoint file="D:\Users\ust5cob\Branch\HW_Verifier\TestCases\Others\TestCaseBase.cpp" line="680"><![CDATA[]]></LastCheckpoint>
            </Exception>
            <TestingTime>535945</TestingTime>
        </TestCase>
    </TestSuite>
</TestSuite>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to use an existing adapter, a quick glance through the existing adapters tells me that [`allure-java`](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java) should be able to deal with the [JUnit format](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/test_output/log_formats/log_junit_format.html) output that boost can make: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/test_output/log_formats.html

If you want to do it more specifically for your own purposes, have someone program a conversion, perhaps using XSLT.